# How to store large arrays of structs - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I am creating a quiz app which has 2 modes (lets call them A & B). Each mode draws 50 random random questions from an array of structs with over 250 values. To clarify, mode A and mode B both have seperate question pools with over 250 questions, so in total there is around 500 questions.

How do I best store these arrays of structs so I can pull them into my View Controller when the user selects the desired test.

Below is an example of the question pool for a mode.

```
// Question models

class QuizQuestion {

    let question: String!
    let answer: Bool!
    let explanation: String!
    var usersAnswer: Bool?
    var answerSubmitted: Bool?

    init(question: String, answer: Bool, explanation: String) {
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.explanation = explanation
    }
}

    var questions = [

    QuizQuestion(question: "Do I like coffee?", answer: true, explanation: "Because it's awesome!"),
    QuizQuestion(question: "Is bacon god's gift to mankind?", answer: true, explanation: "Because it's awesome!"),
    QuizQuestion(question: "Should I take a nap right now?", answer: true, explanation: "You gotta review some code!"),
    QuizQuestion(question: "Should I take a nap right now?", answer: true, explanation: "You gotta review some code!")
]
```

Comment: Do you read those data from database? How do you want to present them (master/detail view or everything at once)?

Comment: All the questions are hardcoded by myself. About how I want to present them - I am very new to Swift and programming in general. I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. I just want to draw 50 questions from the 250 question pool and use those 50 questions in the Question array above.

Comment: You need to clarify. What do you mean by "store"? Hold in memory? Save to disk? An array of 500 questions is small enough that you can simply make it an in-memory array. Unless the questions contain pictures or other multimedia content you can store a **whole** lot of content in a megabyte.

Comment: Hold in memory, sorry! There aren`t any images just the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways to store the questions on disk are:
1) Core data
2) Sqlite

I would suggest the following architecture to retrieve the stored questions:

1) Store 250 questions in core data/sqlite with each question associated with a number 1-250.

2) When you need to select 50 questions randomly, generate 50 random numbers and retrieve the question associated with the random numbers you generated.

This approach will help you store more than 250 questions too.

Explaining core data or sqlite is beyond the scope of this answer. You can easily find tutorials for these online.

About saving in a swift file:
You can declare a struct in a swift file with the questions. I think this would work for 250 questions but the problem with this approach is that it would take up memory. So this is not scalable in case you want to add more questions later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about if the arrays are just stored in the memory.

Comment: Also can I place them in another swift file and call them into another file?

Comment: You can place them in another swift file and call them from a separate file.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was looking for tutorials on that but unable to find any. Would you be able to help quickly explain how to do this?

Comment: Both core data and sqlite are fairly complex to explain. Use this tutorial for core data: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started